# Multiple types of the same type of relationship in django

Tags: django, django-models, database-design

I have a requirement for models with a pk relationship where one of the models can be multiple types of a similar object.

for instance I have three different ways in which a requisition can be made and these three ways have distinct attributes which are different from each other.

How can I make the model so as to connect the three different requisition types with a single order model?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement it as one table with different attributes for each model instance by using a [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.JSONField).

Or you could have three tables, one for each kind of requisition, and use a [generic relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations).